# Access cross-platform schema Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm working on some reports and we're halfway through migrating from Oracle to SQL Server.

The reports I'm migrating are using some user-defined functions from the Oracle schema so the rest of my new translated code obviously does not work with them.

Within Report Builder 3.0 I have access to the data source, how can I provide access to the schema so the functions still work?

I'm sorry if that isn't very clear.

Comment: Are you asking: "How can I get my SQL Server datasource (and query) to access user defined functions in Oracle?"

Comment: have you tried to move function over to SQL Server?

Comment: Yes user3056839.

Vladimir, that's not possible due to the privileges I am yet to receive. I cannot do any admin functions, nor can I access other databases which I do not have the permissions for. Though I am expected to produce these reports without said permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to build a dataset pointed at the Oracle schema that calls the user-defined functions and returns their results, together with the input parameter column(s).  This dataset will need to return a row for every required combination of input parameter column(s).

Then in textbox expressions, I would use the SSRS Lookup function to return the function results from the Oracle dataset.